# Alias required in SELECT list of cursor to avoid duplicate column names

Tags: sql, plsql

I am having an issue doing a plsql command. The idea is to show the courier, location, and yes or not if it is over 20.

```
DECLARE 
 yesnobool VARCHAR(3); 

 CURSOR orders_list IS 
 SELECT shipping.ship_courier, 
 shipping.weightpership,
  shipping.shipping#,
  purchaseorder.shipping#,
  storelocation.location#,
  STORELOCATION.LOC_CITY,
  purchaseorder.location#
 FROM shipping, 
 purchaseorder, 
 storelocation
 WHERE purchaseorder.shipping# = shipping.shipping# 
 and storelocation.location# = purchaseorder.location#;
BEGIN 
 dbms_output.Put_line('Courier || Location || Too Heavy for 1 person lift?'); 
 dbms_output.Put_line('------ -------- -----------------------------------'); 

 FOR an_order IN orders_list LOOP 
 IF SHIPPING.WEIGHTPERSHIP > 20 THEN 
 yesnobool := 'YES'; 
 ELSE 
 yesnobool := 'NO'; 
 END IF; 

 dbms_output.Put_line(Rpad(an_order.ship_courier, 6) || ' ' || 
 Rpad(an_order.loc_city, 8) || ' ' || 
 Rpad(yesnobool, 19)); 
 END LOOP; 
END;
```

The Error message i am getting is:

> Error report -
>   ORA-06550: line 21, column 2:
>   PLS-00402: alias required in SELECT list of cursor to avoid duplicate column names
>   ORA-06550: line 21, column 2:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

Im not very good with plsql so i dont really know how to pin down the issue. Thank you in advance for any and all advice.

Answer (score 3):

Columns `shipping#` and `location#` are duplicated in your select field list.

```
shipping.shipping#
purchaseorder.shipping#

storelocation.location#,
purchaseorder.location#
```

The cursor is unable to distinguish which shipping or location its supposed to use.

The solution is to alias the fields.  Something like this:

```
shipping.shipping# as shipping,
purchaseorder.shipping# as poshipping
```

And:

```
storelocation.location# as storeLocation,
purchaseorder.location# as poLocation
```

Comment: That did let that message go away but another one popped up.

Comment: Which says Error report -
ORA-06550: line 22, column 14:
PLS-00357: Table,View Or Sequence reference 'SHIPPING.WEIGHTPERSHIP' not allowed in this context
ORA-06550: line 22, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: @user3487244 Thats because you're looping through the results now and each row is the `an_order` variable.  Change `SHIPPING.WEIGHTPERSHIP` to `an_order.WEIGHTPERSHIP`

Comment: @user3487244, whats the latest on this, were you able to get it to work?

Comment: i have not been able to get it to work, i have been working on my php final project. This is from my database class.

Comment: Actually it worked after @user3487244 your suggestion worked perfect. I hope to be knowledgeable enough to be able to help people like me.

Comment: @user3487244 if my solution worked, then please make sure to mark it as answered and upvote! thats how we say thanks. :)